# Consequence of local duality

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a local Cohen-Macaulay ring of dimension $d$ with a canonical module $\omega.$ Let $M,N$ be maximal Cohen-Macaulay $R$-modules. Then local duality implies 
$$\mathrm{Ext}^i(N,\mathrm{Hom}(M,\omega))=\mathrm{Ext}^i(M,\mathrm{Hom}(N,\omega)).$$

It will be really helpful if someone explains the above equality using local duality.

(Here by local duality I mean $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Ext}^i(M,\omega),E)\cong H_{\mathfrak m}^{d-i}(M)$ where $E$ is the injective hull of residue field of $R.$)

Comment: What is the reference for the equality? I am a bit confused as with $R = k[[x]], M = R, N = R/m, i = 1$, one has $Ext^1(k,Hom(R,R))= Ext^1 (k , R) \neq 0$ (depth 1), but
$Ext^1(R,Hom(N,\omega)) = 0$ as $R$ is projective.

Comment: I have edited and put the condition Cohen-Macaulay on N and M.